# What word(s) combine the meaning of 'faith' and 'discernment'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word, a noun, that combines the meaning of the words 'faith' (in the religious sense) and 'discernment'. The word needs to fit in the sentence "Bob wants to have [insert word here]".

Basically, I want a word that says "this individual is careful about placing his loyalty in the correct truths". So he has discernment about where he places his faith.

I feel like there has to be a word for this. It's a very specific meaning, but in all the long history of all religion I feel like SOMEBODY has to have come up with an English word for this. The closest I've gotten so far is "wisdom" and just allowing the religious context give the word some religious connotation. Maybe you can help?

Comment: I find your display name "interesting". "discerning_faith".

Comment: I'm not convinced there's a meaningful real-world concept behind this. I simply don't believe "discerning" people really can use their powers of discrimination to select the "best" religion in any "objective" sense. I might claim to have a discerning palate which leads me to insist on only drinking Coca-Cola, for example, whereas someone else with an equally discerning palate might prefer Pepsi. At the end of the day, "discerning" in such contexts simply means "capable of telling the difference, and having a preference", so perhaps the best word is just ***fussy***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you're a materialist, you reason from an epistemological position and/or worldview that many would find self-refuting upon examination. But more to the point, *fussy* doesn't fit "this individual is careful about placing his loyalty in the correct truths" at all. Nor does it work with the OP's sentence.

Comment: @A.P.: Define "correct truths". You can be careful about which *individuals* you place your "faith, trust" in (and avoid lending money to people who aren't likely to pay you back, for example). But clearly there's no real objective way to rank different religions as better or worse, so the idea of making a "discerning" choice between possible alternative faiths strikes me as nonsense. Even devout theists don't normally consider their *specific* faith to be a "choice" in the sense that they could reasonably have chosen a *different* one. You either believe or you don't.

Comment: @A.P. There is no way "discernment" can be involved in whatever you think is correct truth. I think that's what FumbleFingers means.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think this is the right place for a worldview discussion. It'll snowball out of control very soon and is off-topic. I won't define "correct truths" (it's not necessary to answer the OP's question at all), and I won't ask you to define "real", "objective", etc. Discernment simply means "keenness of insight and judgment". I think that's more than enough to deal with the question at hand here.

Comment: @A.P.: The whole point of my first comment was to steer things away from "worldview discussion" issues that might arise in the context of religious faith. So far as *use of English* is concerned, it seems to me it would be just as relevant and less "divisive" to ask about making a "discerning choice" between different brands of cola.

Comment: @Rathony I think your statement is defensible within certain worldviews, but not others. But Bob in OP's sentence clearly has a worldview in which it's possible to determine the correctness of spiritual truths. And that's enough to answer the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You may think you have some neutral ground, but I don't think you do. You have a worldview just like everybody else, which you presuppose. In yours, discerning between spiritual truths equals discerning between fizzy drinks. For many others this is not so at all. Clearly, Bob in OP's sentence doesn't share your worldview. So why force it on the poor chap?

Comment: @A.P. That's exactly why this question is off-topic and should be closed. At the same time, I don't think it is appropriate to jump to conclusion about what FumbleFingers wanted to express with his opinion. "Dicernment" is an abstract noun. That means it can mean anything you could imagine.

Comment: Would it help perhaps to replace the word *discernment* with *reason*? It is just that the Anglican Church proposes that its beliefs and practices are based on *faith, tradition(including scripture) and reason* (the three legged stool). It has led to their becoming a confession that encompasses just about anyone, from clergy who do not believe in a literal God, to staunch evangelists. Does the three-legged-stool metaphor help?

Comment: @Rathony I disagree the question is off-topic, but most of the ensuing discussion in comments certainly is. The OP's question, I think, is obviously a normal request for a similar word or synonym. As far as FumbleFingers, his opinion and my conclusions go, I didn't try to jump to conclusions, merely get to the bottom of the issue, which is the underlying worldview. What *is* inappropriate, to my mind, is to force your worldview on Bob. Especially without backing yours up.

Comment: @Rathony: I don't necessarily think the question should be closed (I haven't closevoted myself - *yet!* :) I just think that specifically mentioning *religious* choice unnecessarily opens up a can of worms when in all probability what OP is really asking about is a term to describe someone who is thoughtful and methodical about *whatever* they choose to believe in or endorse (religion, cola, car fuel, or whatever).

Comment: @A.P. I understand your points fully. Shall we start to delete our off-topic comments with discernment? I respect both your and FumbleFingers' opinion.

Comment: @Rathony: I'd leave them for the time being. They may prompt OP to "improve" the question text, or help others to understand the issues involved here before posting an answer. The mods will probably tidy things up later, but it's early days for the question as yet.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree the *question* opens a can of worms, though worldview discussions may certainly do that. You don't have to agree with or question Bob's worldview, or label it "nonsense" to answer the question, just answer according to Bob's worldview, that's all. That said, I'd like OP to clarify Bob's worldview, as I don't think the same word would work for all religions.

Comment: I think it's hilarious how you guys wandered off into the realm of philosophy! I know it's a really tempting direction to take this, but that's not what I'm wanting. I'm just looking for a word that captures a particular idea. I don't care if that particular idea fits into your philosophical system or not.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want "discernment," but with a spiritual connotation.  "Discernment" *can* have such a connotation:  "discernment of spirits" is one of the gifts of the Spirit in 1 Corinthians (KJV).

The reason I don't think you're finding a word that is *only* used in a spiritual context is that discernment is something that applies in a variety of contexts.  Baptism only makes sense in a spiritual context; same for pyx, manse, paten, and (with the particular meanings assigned) justification and salvation; but "discernment," with the meaning you want, works well in secular contexts as well.

You didn't say what you wanted this for.  If you're writing and want the right connotation, the rest of your text will provide the connotation for you.

Comment: You make a good point. I personally think the word 'discernment' feels a little passive, so I was looking for one with more action tied to it, like 'faith'. If nothing better comes along, I'll have to reconsider this point. And it would take a while for me to describe why I need exactly one word for this, so I left that information out of the post--it wouldn't add any value to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, **religious insight**.

> INSIGHT
>
> : an instance of apprehending he true nature of a thing, esp. Through intuitive understanding.
>
> : penetrating mental vision or discernment.

[Random-House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insight)

Comment: This is a very interesting suggestion. "Apprehending true nature" applies to the 'discernment' part, and "through intuitive understanding" applies to the 'faith' part. I'll keep this answer in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Opposite to "blind faith", **reasoned faith** may fit (even if not a single word).

> *This comment found on the web illustrates the difference between these two types of faith*:
>
> Blind faith is the belief in something when there is evidence that is
> contrary to the belief reasoned faith is a faith in something which
> can not be proven but the corrolary arguements to the belief are
> examinable.
>
> For example--blind faith is those who believe in the literal
> interpretation of the abrahamic myth book. There is ample evidence
> that the stories as written couldn't possibly be true. Those with
> blind faith therefore must scurry into the supernatural hand waving
> explanations
>
> Reasoned faith is like many of the religous--who accept the bible as
> allegorical and not literal. You still can't prove your faith--but
> your faith is consistent with factual evidence. [*source*](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110406111658AADu6Yc)

*EDIT following OP comment for a single word*:

To convey both "wisdom" and "religion", **spirituality** is a possibility.

> All religions emphasise spirituality as being an important part of
> faith. But, spirituality is more of an individual practice and has to do with
> having a sense of peace and purpose. It also relates to the process of
> developing beliefs around the meaning of life and connection with
> others. [*source*](http://au.reachout.com/what-is-spirituality)

Comment: You've pinpointed the reason I was wanting to avoid the word 'faith' alone. I feel that when people hear the word 'faith' by itself it brings to mind the "blind faith" concept your comment describes, and I want to steer clear from that. But I still need it to be one word, not two.

Comment: @discerning_faith - I edited my answer to propose "spirituality".

Answer (score -1):

The word I would use is "belief."

Comment: What makes you think "belief" has a connotation of "discernment" while faith doesn't.

Comment: @Rathony What the OP asked for was a word which combined both *faith* and *discernment*. So perhaps *belief* is not a bad pot shot.

Comment: @WS2 That's as much opinion-based. I don't want to argue about the difference between faith and belief.

Comment: I don't find this response to be very helpful.